# drupal_view or views_embed_view doesn't show translated content

Tags: views, 8

I have a block view on a multi-language website. Rendering Language is set to `Content language selected for page` and the translated content is displayed correctly in the admin page.

I embed this view like `{{ drupal_view('ipa_projects_map') }}` inside twig but at that page the content in original language is displayed, ignoring the content language selected for page setting.

Any ideas why?

PS: `drupal_view` is provided by "Twig Tweak" module and utilizes `views_embed_view`

Comment: `twig tweak` seems to support translatable content as per this issue https://www.drupal.org/node/2833546 ... Can you tell us how you setup `admin/config/regional/language/detection` ?

Comment: Language is detected by url, `/en` for english and `/tr` for turkish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The view is configured to be a "block" and the "rendering language" setting belongs to the "block" definition I guess. So I added the block id and now it renders in the correct language:

```
{{ drupal_view('ipa_projects_map', 'block_1') }}
```